# How does the 'Where is this used' button/functionality work behind the scenes?

Tags: apex, custom-field

I was recently working on a similar functionality as 'Where is this used' and used the MetadataComponentDependency.

The Salesforce standard feature does not show us fields referenced if the code is commented. Can someone here tell me how Salesforce does this? It does not seem like a simple text based search on all metadata files with the current field being checked. This is just a matter of great curiosity and please let me know if this question is unnecessary before downvoting and I will delete this.